# Каким образом отправлять уведомления конкретному юзеру в Node.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Нашел вот этот код, но если с отправкой сообщения самому себе и всем кроме себя все понятно, то где `io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit` вообще ничего не понятно. Откуда берется `io.sockets`, что такое `socketid`? Просто нашел ответ на вопрос, и этот код якобы из доков, но в доках я не нашел похожего.

```
// отправить текущему сокету сформировавшему запрос (туда откуда пришла)
socket.emit('message', "this is a test");

// отправить всем пользователям, включая отправителя
io.sockets.emit('message', "this is a test");

// отправить всем, кроме отправителя
socket.broadcast.emit('message', "this is a test");

// отправить всем клиентам в комнате (канале) 'game', кроме отправителя
socket.broadcast.to('game').emit('message', 'nice game');

// отправить всем клиентам в комнате (канале) 'game', включая отправителя
io.sockets.in('game').emit('message', 'cool game');

// отправить конкретному сокету, по socketid
io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
```

Есть ли решение которое просто позволяет отправлять личное сообщение по логину юзера, id сессии или как-то еще?

Answer (score 0):

socketId - уникальный идентификатор сокета, который создается при подключении, чтобы отправлять по логину юзера или по его ид - нужно хранить в кеше все текущие подключения сокетов, в роли кеша может выступать как обычный объект `const liveConnections = {name: {/*объект сокета*/}}`, так и субд, redis например. И по нужному тебе ключу потом вытягивать  ид `io.sockets.socket(liveConnections['Вася'].id).emit('message', 'Привет!')`

---

Comment: Естественно при отключении юзера нужно удалять его из текущих подключений.